# Cos'è una "patecchia"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> E Prodi è schiacciato. E anche
>   noi siamo schiacciati come **patecchie**, perché adesso risale in groppa il cavaliere errante con tutta la sua ghenga
>   che come per miracolo si è ricompattata all’istante. E noi
>   possiamo cantare il Miserere!

Sapreste spiegarmi cos'è una "patecchia"? Non ho trovato questo termine su nessuno dei dizionari che ho consultato. Si tratta di un vocabolo di uso regionale?

Comment: Una variante di “[petecchia](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/petecchia)”, magari? Ma non so se vengano schiacciate...

Comment: Se usiamo come definizione di petecchia la prima del link alla Treccani, cioè di una piccola macchia cutanea dovuta ad una emorragia, questa si presenta come "piatta" (non è un gonfiore) e questo è coerente con l'espressione "schiacciati come..." - ho interpretato "schiacciato" nel senso di "piatto" - o il brano ha un'altra interpretazione?

Comment: Probabilmente hai ragione, @RiccardoDeContardi. Sulle prime avevo inteso “schiacciati come...” nel senso di qualcosa che si è soliti schiacciare, ma come dici tu, facendo riferimento alla forma, ha più senso.

Comment: Si potrebbe anche dire "stretti come sardine" o "schiacciati come sogliole" ;)